# MySQL SSL program "mysql_ssl_rsa_setup"

Tags: mysql, ssl

The MySQL 5.7 documentation makes reference to, and describes, a program called [mysql_ssl_rsa_setup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-ssl-rsa-setup.html), which is supposed to make SSL certificate and key generation for encryption much "easier".

I cannot find this anywhere in the source distribution, so my guess is that it hasn't been added to the 5.7 distribution yet. Has anyone had any luck finding such a program or, failing that, can describe the process it takes in generating certificates? I have tried doing this via multiple methods without much luck (right now I'm getting ERROR 2026).

Comment: It is because of  Setting Up SSL Certificates and Keys for MySQL. Kindly refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-certs.html

Comment: I have tried this method (albeit using the 5.6 documentation), which is what resulted in ERROR 2026 when connecting.

Answer (score 1):

The code can be found here:

https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/client/mysql_ssl_rsa_setup.cc

How mysql_rsa_ssl_setup fits into the larger picture of enabling easier TLS connections is described here:

http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2015/04/09/ssltls-in-mysql-5-7/

The mysql_ssl_rsa_setup executable attempts to generate key material required for TLS connections to MySQL Server. It is typically invoked by package deployment scripts, rather than directly called by end users. It is part of the larger effort in MySQL Server 5.7 to enable TLS connections by default

Comment: It might be helpful to quote the most relevant part of the blog post here. That way, if the blog post is no longer available in five years, the answer will still be helpful.

Comment: The mysql_ssl_rsa_setup executable attempts to generate key material required for TLS connections to MySQL Server.  It is typically invoked by package deployment scripts, rather than directly called by end users.  It is part of the larger effort in MySQL Server 5.7 to enable TLS connections by default.

Comment: Please edit your added information into the answer rather than adding it as a comment. You should assume that comments can be deleted at any time, so your answer should be complete without them.